# Running Hadoop Map Reduce Job, Error: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, amazon-web-services

I am running a using hadoop 2.2.0 to run a map-reduce job on Amazon Web Services Red Hat 6.4. The Jar file that I'm using was built on my local Windows 7 Computer. The map reduce job runs fine on a local installation of Hadoop on my Windows 7 machine, but when I try to run it on the Amazon Instance I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: mapReduce/Tes
tXMLConfig : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:205)
```

I've done some research and it seems like this error is generated when you run a Jar file that was build in a newer version of Java on a system that is running an older version of Java. However, when I run 'java -version' on my Windows 7 system (where the Jar file is built using Eclipse Kepler) it 
gives me the following:

java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)

When I run it on my Amazon Web Services Red Hat 6.4 Instance it also gives:

java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)

Both systems are using the exact same build of Java so I'm not sure how mismatched java versions could be the problem. In Eclipse, when I go to Window > Java > Complier, I can see that the "Compiler Compliance Level" is 1.7. But Hadoop with Java 1.8 should be able to run Jar files built on older versions of Java (It runs on Windows 7 machine using java 1.8).

I can't seem to find any problem here. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Is your Eclipse project using the 1.8 JRE System Library?

Comment: `bin/hadoop` is a script file. At the end of that file you can echo out the `$JAVA` variable to see exactly which version of the JVM you're running. It's probably `/etc/alternatives/java`, which will point to some OS-standard install.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my problem. Even though I had java 1.8 installed, the bin/hadoop script file was trying to run with java 1.6.

Comment: @Hi_Im_Tim. Where did u write the echo statement?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the home directory of your JDK.  I've previously encountered this error and my java -version would be correct but JAVA_HOME was not set.  After setting JAVA_HOME to my JDK Contents Home I no longer encountered this issue.

Note - this occurred on a Macbook for me, and with a different piece of software.

Comment: My JAVA_HOME wasn't set to anything, so I set it to the location of the jdk1.8.0/bin directory, but I still get the error.

Comment: @Hi_Im_Tim - `JAVA_HOME` should be set to the base directory of the Java install, not the `bin` directory.

Comment: @Hi_Im_Tim It shouldn't be set to bin, as kdgregory said.  For example, my current JAVA_HOME is /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home